# Can Port Control Protocol (PCP) work for two ISP customers that want to host a service on same port within CGN?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, nat, isp

Let's say there are ISP customers that were assigned to a shared address space of CGN. connections were established and PCP client is enabled. Now what happens if two customers wanted to host a webserver on port 80? Can PCP establish that connection on two simultaneous identical hosts behind CGN? Or will it reserve the first port request to whoever customer requested the incoming connection first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both customers also share the same external IP address, then it is impossible to make this work. The incoming request packet needs to be routed to one server *or* the other, and there's no way for the CGN gateway to know which server the client actually wants – the only thing it can match the rule against is the destination port, which is always the same 80 in both cases.

(An HTTP or TLS application-layer proxy could know the requested domain name, but a TCP/UDP transport-layer CGN gateway doesn't have this information.)